# SELECT time from datetime

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

We have a python program on our own cloud, where we want to fetch data from MySQL database, and use it for analysis. So far, we want to select time from a datetime.

Example: *'02/11-2019 18:20:00' --> SELECT '18:20:00'*

We're attempting to do this with the following lines of code:

```
test = pd.read_sql('SELECT CAST(time_end AS time(0)) FROM Raw_Validated WHERE third_temp_lpn = "%s"' % (list_lpn_temp[-1]), conn).astype(str).values
times.extend(test)
print (times)
```

For some reason, when printing also '0 days' is added, so that our print looks like:

[image]

**IN TEXT**

```
2019-07-26 19:00:00  |  2019-07-26 19:20:00
[array(['0 days 19:20:00.000000000'], dtype=object)]
2019-07-27 03:00:00  |  2019-07-27 03:20:00
[array(['0 days 19:20:00.000000000'], dtype=object), array(['0 days 12:40:00.000000000'], dtype=object), array(['0 days 17:00:00.000000000'], dtype=object), array(['0 days 11:20:00.000000000'], dtype=object)]
2019-07-27 22:20:00  |  2019-07-27 22:40:00
[array(['0 days 19:20:00.000000000'], dtype=object), array(['0 days 12:40:00.000000000'], dtype=object), array(['0 days 17:00:00.000000000'], dtype=object), array(['0 days 11:20:00.000000000'], dtype=object)]
```

Why does this happen, and what can we do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the conversion/cutting to the python part of the app, I think this is easier than casting on the database:

```
import datetime

sql_time = "2019-11-12 18:20:00"
time_end = datetime.datetime.strptime(sql_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(time_end.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

As you are using pandas, you can shouldn't cast the datetime object, as pandas can do this itself:

Series.dt.time - Returns numpy array of datetime.time (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html)

Comment: The case is that sometimes, the SELECT catches more than just one value. As there might be several coincidences to third_temp_lpn to be equal with a value. Then I would be forced to go through every value and format them. Will this not be a bad option? Perhaps the right SQL query would be better? Or a correction of this query

Comment: Well that depends on the use-case, which I don't know anything about. I guess at some point you have to iterate over all the results anyways? Because you want to process them further or display them? I don't have mysql to test, but this query should work: `SELECT time_end, TIME(time_end) as time_only FROM Raw_Validated WHERE third_temp_lpn = "%s"`, see https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-time-function.php

Comment: Unfortunately still write (0 days... ). Have tried with TIME() before, but giving same error. Also the strptime only applies for str and not for np.arrays

Comment: I guess pandas is still recognizing it as datetime and converting it. There are properties in pandas which will return the time part of a datetime. See my updated answer.